# Redirecting to https/Apache

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

How can I write a rewrite rule to redirect below rule to use HTTPS only
without mentioning domain name. Below rule redirects to http home page.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/$1?x-orig-uri=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When redirecting to https, you need to specify the full URL, including protocol and domain name. You could use a variable if you don't want to hardcode the name tho:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/$1?x-orig-uri=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```